# PHP shows that file_exists but when call "readFile", the browser says no data is received or connection reset

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to write a script that reads out a file for download. This script has worked on every other PHP server I've used it on. But I'm getting the following errors:

```
(In Firefox) The connection was reset. The connection to the server was 
             reset while the page was loading.

(In Chrome) No data received. Unable to load the webpage because the 
            server sent no data
```

When I check that the file exists, it **does**!

```
//This prints "1"
echo file_exists( "my.pdf" );
```

But when I try to read out the file, I get the errors.

```
<?php
//If I remove these headers it is able to print the file data to the web page
header( "Pragma: public" );
header( "Expires: 0" );
header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header( "Cache-Control: private", false );
header( "Content-Type: application/pdf" );
header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"my.pdf\";" );
header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
header( "Content-Length: ". filesize( "my.pdf" ) );

//If I take out this line, it works!
if ( file_exists( "my.pdf" ) ) readfile( "my.pdf" );
?>
```

What could be wrong?

### **SETUP**

**The File Size**: 500K

**OS:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1

**PHP:** PHP Version 5.4.7

**Modules:** core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_ssl mod_status mod_php5

**upload_max_size:** 2M (this is bigger than the file I'm attempting to read)

**cURL Largefile:** yes

**EDIT**

Here's the headers (printed to the page to show their values):

```
Pragma: public
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Length: 489936
```

Comment: Can you `echo` the header values instead of passing them to `header()` and post the results?

Comment: @AlexW done. It's appended to the end of my post.

Comment: @AlexW I don't think it's a duplicate. There are not a lot of visitors to the web server and the file's size is so small (500K) that those values (as reported in php.ini) are never hit.

Comment: Hmm. I just tested that exact code and it worked for downloading a PDF off my server.

Comment: @AlexW yes, and it works on other servers for me too. I wonder if it's some issue with it being a windows php install? Or what configuration on the server or web server or php could be causing this?

Comment: Have you looked at the HTTP headers with Chrome DevTools, or Firebug? Also, check to see if Apache or PHP are crashing or running out of memory.

Comment: @AlexW yes, but the Chrome devtools show the headers, etc for the Chrome-created page "No Data Received". And PHP can't be crashing since I can still view the website and the page when I simply comment out the relevant code.